# z-score using arithmetical mean or annual compounded return

Tags: mathematical-statistics, z-score

I want to predict the probability of a specific stock market index return based on a set of 90 yearly returns.

For doing that, I thought about normalizing the data and then use the z-score to estimate the probability. Is this the best way to proceed?

When I try to calculte the z-score, I need to choose the average return. Should I use the average of yearly returns (11.3%) or the annual compounded return (9.5%)

I fell like 9.5% is a much more realistic return and closer to want an investor will get on average.

Comment: What do you mean by simple arithmetical mean, that 2016 had a return of 10%, 2017 had a return of 20%, and 2018 had a return of 30%, so the average return over that period was 20% per year?

Comment: Which one you should use depends on what you are trying to predict. But why do you think z scores will help, in either case? Are annual returns normally distributed? And why not just use the distribution of returns?

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, I am looking at the S&P500 yearly returns for the last 90 years. When I mean arithmetical mean, I mean summing all 90 returns and divide by 90. This 90 years average gives me a 11.3% return. I sould indeed first look if the data are normally distributed. How would I go about making a prediction using just the distribution of returns?

Comment: You have 90 values. Based on that, you can give a percentile rank to any return.